# SAS Folder mapping

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have created a SAS folder say "/Public Development/Area Name/Project Name" under "Folders" tab of SAS Management console.

In SAS EG this folder shows under "SAS Folder" option. I'm able to save EGP project and stored processes in this folder but not SAS code, log etc.

I believe its just a folder at meta data level and only items registered at meta data can be saved here.

So what approach should I take to organize my other project items like code, jobs, macros, Reports...?

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Guide model includes storing your code *as part of your EGP project*.  You put code modules in process flows, and log and output are stored alongside them (in a somewhat similar fashion to if you had run them in batch mode - log, output, and program are grouped as one entity effectively).

Your organization may have specific rules for how code/etc. is stored, such as storing it in a SVN repository or similar, so you should check with your manager or site SAS admin to get a more complete answer that is specific to your site.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to keep metadata folders for storing metadata objects (stored processes, DI jobs, etc), and I use OS file system for storing code (.sas files), .log files, etc and .egp projects.  Generally I don't store code as part of the EG project, instead the project just links to code that is sitting in the OS file system.   So basically, I store my code, logs, macros, format catalogs, output reports, etc etc the same way as I did when I was using PC SAS.